# Can't access to response object with props

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im building an app with reactjs & redux and facing the following problem.

So basically I have a function like this :

```
onAdmissionFormSubmit(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 const { user } = this.props
 console.log(user);
 // If I do this const id = user.member.externalMemberId .... 
 // doesnt throw an error but if I log my const id it just says its undefined
}
```

It actually logs my object but if want to access the data inside of the object like `user.member.externalMemberId` it actually doesnt return an error but it will just says undefined.
What is it that im doing wrong?

console log of user:  http://prntscr.com/fcxmou

Comment: seems like `member` is undefined then. are you sure it's there?

Comment: what happens if you log this `user.member.externalMemberId` ?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of undefined`
That what i get...Weird right?

Comment: are you sure you did a `bind` to the mothod in the constructor?

Comment: I forgot to bind it in the constructor method, now its working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments it seems that `user` is `undefined`, that leads me to believe that either you don't have a `user` object in `this.props` or you don't have a `props` object in `this`.
If it is the second choice, that can happen if you don't `bind` the handler method in to the `class`. In this situation, `this` refers to the element that triggered the handler and not to the class like you would expect.
You should do the binding in the `constructor` of the `class`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onAdmissionFormSubmit = this.onAdmissionFormSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to bind it!